# How to run Haskell Platform after build

Tags: compiling, haskell

I built the haskell platform as stated on the haskell package site.

After `make install` I was told the files were installed to `/usr/local/bin`

How do I run the haskell platform after this step?

Answer (score 2):

Haskell has to be started with `ghci` command.

Visit [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_5_steps) and see.

Also refer this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964907/installing-haskell-on-ubuntu-12) question.

You can run a Haskell by:

```
runhaskell [FILENAME].hs
```

Or

```
ghc [FILENAME].hs
```

Comment: ghci was working right after I installed GHC. But where should I start the Haskell Platform itself from?